# Incorrect password can access database in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I create posgresql db user named 'user'.
Password: django1234.

And I type the database info in settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': '1q2w3e',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

The password does not match definitely. However, it can access the 'test DB' when I run the server, which means, I guess, that anyone can access my DB. What is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in pg_hba.conf file?  If it doesn't require a password (trust, peer, etc.), then you can connect without one (or with a wrong one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably set the access to `trust` in your configuration. Check for `pg_hba.conf` file, on Debian/Ubuntu and for PostgreSQL 10 it's located at `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf` (Check directory like "Program Files\PostgreSQL\data" on Windows). Find the following line:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

and change it to:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

if your user is a system user too.

Restart your server afterward with `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`. On Windows that can be done with "Reload configuration" shortcut from the PostgreSQL start menu folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the authentication method for the user `test@localhost` is `trust`, meaning that Postgres is not asking for password to accept a connection. Please refer 
[the Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for further details.

Comment: Thank you for your help!